# Как запустить две функции одновременно?

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing, parallel

Есть две функции: `hello()` и `world()`

```
def hello():
 while(True):
    print('hello')
def world():
 while(True):
    print('world')
```

Пытаюсь запустить их одновременно. Мой код :

```
from threading import Thread
def hello():
 while(True):
    print('hello')
def world():
 while(True):
    print('world')

thread1 = Thread(target=hello())
thread2 = Thread(target=world())

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

По итогу в консоль выводится только "hello".
То есть они запускаются не параллельно, а как-бы по очереди.
Как можно сделать так что-бы они работали именно параллельно?

Comment: Эээ, а как вы думаете будет писаться в терминал/консоль ОДНОВРЕМЕННО?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, он хочет чтобы вывелось "hweolrllod")

Comment: @TigerTV.ru XD XD XD

Comment: Ожидал что вывод будет примерно такой : hello world hello world и т.д

Comment: @SuddenDumb, мы шутим просто.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

проблема здесь

```
Thread(target=hello())
```

вы вызвали функцию из-за чего она запустилась как обычная, а не в потоке. Надо убрать круглые скобки после названия функции

Comment: Вы правы, теперь работает как предполагалось, единственное интересно, почему вывод выглядит примерно так: helloworld

worldhello

hello
worldhello
hello

worldhello

worldhello

world
worldhello

hello
world
world
hello
world
world
helloworld

Comment: Потоки работают несинхронно. Их синхронизация - работа программиста.